# ScrollToAsync .Net Maui only Works the second time I press the button

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, maui

I am working currently on a chat program and when I display the chat history of two people, I want to scroll to the last message/end of the Vertical Stack Layout --> I do it with the .ScrollToAsync Function.

If I click one of the User Buttons, then the History gets loaded from a local storing method. After that the program creates a label for every message and adds it to the scrollable vertical stack layout. After that it should scroll to the end of the vertical stack layout. With the following code snippet:

```
await Scroller.ScrollToAsync(TextField, ScrollToPosition.End, false);
```

The complete method is here:

```
private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_currentLabels != null)
        {
            foreach(Label label in m_currentLabels)
            {
                TextField.Remove(label);
            }
        }

        m_currentLabels = new List<Label>();
        Button button =(Button) sender;
        string str = button.Text;
        Guid userId = m_userDictionary[str];
        List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>();
        guids.Add(userId);
        m_currChannelPartners = guids;

        List<MessageModel> localMessages = m_eChatBusiness.GetMessages(MessageModel.Yourself.ID, guids);
        foreach(MessageModel message in localMessages)
        {
            Label messageLabel = new Label();
            messageLabel.Text = $"{message.Created} {message.Message} | {GetStatus(message)}";
            messageLabel.TextColor = Color.Parse("White");
            messageLabel.HorizontalTextAlignment = message.Position == "End"? TextAlignment.End:TextAlignment.Start;
            m_currentLabels.Add(messageLabel);
            TextField.Add(messageLabel);
        }

        await Scroller.ScrollToAsync(TextField, ScrollToPosition.End, false); 
    }
```

Scroller is the ScrollView and the TextField is the vertical stack layout.

The weird thing is: It works, when I click the button a second time. I tried to guess, but since I call the asynchronous function at the end of the method, the TextField should be fully  initialized or not?

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Should have worked - Sounds like a maui layout bug. Testing on Android? Wait for the next release (later this month) - devs had to roll back a recent change that caused multiple layout bugs.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I am working on Windows currently. I have to wait then, thanks. (It's pretty new anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for that problem, with the help of my chief:

You have to enable a timer object, which gets a function, which is calling the desired function Scroller.ScrollToAsync(TextField, ScrollToPosition.End, false) inside the mainThread (because otherwise an exception is thrown). Important is the Infinite Timeout, so that the action only executes one time.

Here is the code, if somebody has the same Problem:

```
Timer timer = new Timer((object obj) => {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Scroller.ScrollToAsync(TextField, ScrollToPosition.End, false));
        }, null, 100, Timeout.Infinite);
```

The 100 are the time how long the timer objects waits, before execution. The really good thing now is, that the UI is not blocked anymore!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this method worked for me.  I followed their documentation and I couldn't get anything to scroll.  If I called ScrollToAsync once it didn't work.  If I called it twice then it wouldn't scroll, but once I manually scrolled THEN it scrolled to the bottom. I never would have thought to put it into a timer.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but wanted to reply to the "workaround" that uses a timer. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72893292/22299956)

The counter clicked void is async - so as rightly pointed out in the answer, the code needs to be invoked on the main thread, however you don't need a timer to do this. You can use:

```
Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => Scroller.ScrollToAsync(...));
```

Dispatcher is a property on BindableObject - so your page, control etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.bindableobject.dispatcher?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. 
Please reformat your post to include the context of the other answer and it's "workaround" and it can be accepted as an answer than a comment. Comments posted as answers are often deleted.

Including the context of what you are replying to in your answer helps readers if the other answer is deleted in the future.